# Mysql subquery multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The query

```
SELECT artists.artist_id, images.img_id 
FROM `artists`, `images` 
WHERE artists.artist_id = :artist_id 
AND images.artist_id = :artist_id
```

returns the following for example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [artist_id] => 80
        [img_id] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [artist_id] => 80
        [img_id] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [artist_id] => 80
        [img_id] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [artist_id] => 80
        [img_id] => 140
    )

)
```

How do I make it so that it returns the `artist_id` only **once** and the image IDs in a separate array?
I have tried `INNER JOIN images ON images.artist_id = :artist_id` as well, but returns something similar.

Comment: this can be better done in php side by looping through results and making new array for images,mysql is not a programming language

Comment: Database result sets are generally rectangular. If you want something different, you have to do it yourself. Note that it is often not hard to process data in the format you have now by just `. using `ORDER BY artist_id` and 2. Remembering the last `artist_id` and doing a comparison against the current `artist_id` to find out if you're switching artists.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid this should be done in php. it would be not following the rules of normalization to set up a database structure like the OP is asking about to return the data in that way. simple loop in php should work. thats why i upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this on your php side. it would be much easier

**DISCLAIMER:** I have written php maybe twice.. so i'm in no way an expert in php.. but this is what I would try to do. anyone feel free to correct the code if its faulty ;)

**SETUP:** I created an array of arrays just like how you have it. 
made an empty array called image_ids
pushed the img_id on that array to get just an array of the img_id 's

```
$test = Array
(
 Array
    (
        artist_id => 80,
        img_id => 4
    ),

Array
    (
        artist_id => 80,
        img_id => 5
    ),

Array
    (
        artist_id => 80,
        img_id => 6
    ),

Array
    (
        artist_id => 80,
        img_id => 140
    )

);
```

**AFTER SETUP -- IT'S CODING TIME!:**

```
$image_ids = Array();
$artist = 0;
foreach ($test as $my_array){ // $test is the variable the whole array is equal to
    array_push($image_ids, $my_array['img_id']);
}
$artist = $my_array['artist_id']; // my_artist is the last element in the array currently

echo 'the artist is: ', $artist;
echo 'the images he made are :';
print_r ($image_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run two separate queries:

```
SELECT artists.artist_id
  FROM `artists`
 WHERE artists.artist_id = :artist_id 

SELECT images.img_id
  FROM `images`
 WHERE images.artist_id = :artist_id
```

If the datatypes of those two columns are equivalent (i.e. both are integer), we could combine the two queries (using a `UNION ALL` set operator`to return a single list of id values. We could add a discriminator column to the result set, to identify which rows are from the`artists`table, and which are from the`images` table.

For example:

```
SELECT 'artist_id'         AS src
     , artists.artist_id   AS id
  FROM `artists`
 WHERE artists.artist_id = :artist_id 
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'img_id'            AS src
  FROM images.img_id
  FROM `images`
 WHERE images.artist_id = :artist_id
```